# How to repeat the form data according to integer value get from the select box.?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How can form elements be repeated as many times as chosen by (the value of a) select box?
        I tried to get the value from the select box and based on that integer value, the form should be repeated. For example in select box, selecting *2* means the form should display 2 times.
     My html code is:

```
<select id="sel" class="sel">
<?php
$v=1; 
while($v<=10){
    ?>      
<option value="$v"> <?php echo $v; ?></option>
<?php $v++; } ?></select>
<button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
<div>name:<input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
</div>
<div id="inrlog" style="display:none;">
   <div>name:<input type="text" name="selname"></div>
 </div>
```

and my Javascript is:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
var e = document.getElementById("sel");




$("#sel").select(function(){

   $("#sel").click(function(){
    $("#inrlog").show("slow");
});

});
```

Comment: Where is the form code?

Comment: this is my sample code. here i try to display div idinrlog. i want to disply this for the count of, value chooses in a select box

Comment: what the reason for giving not use full question to my question, i dont knw who done this..!! if you can't get my quetion means, ask me for some clear information....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Attach an event listener to `select` and as per the value of the select input, con-cat input field to be appended and `.append()` in the container.

You can do this using `for-loop`

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#sel").on('change', function() {
     var counter = parseInt(this.value, 10);
     var html = '<div>name:<input type="text" name="selname">\
  </div>';
     var str = "";
     for (var i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
       str += html;
     }
     $("#inrlog").empty().append(str);
   })
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select id="sel" class="sel">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
  <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
  <div>name:
    <input type="text" name="mytext[]">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="inrlog">
</div>
```

If you want it to happen on button click then:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".add_field_button").on('click', function() {
     var counter = parseInt($('#sel').val(), 10);
     var html = '<div>name:<input type="text" name="selname">\
  </div>';
     var str = "";
     for (var i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
       str += html;
     }
     $("#inrlog").empty().append(str);
   })
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select id="sel" class="sel">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>
  <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
  <div>name:
    <input type="text" name="mytext[]">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="inrlog">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following:

```
$('.add_field_button').on('click', function() {
  var total_to_create = $('#sel').val();
  var new_form = $('#inrlog > div').clone();
  for( i = 1; i <= total_to_calculate; i++ ) {
    new_form.appendTo( '#inrlog' );
  }

  $('#inrlog').show();
});
```

and your `inrlog` div should have following format for input field:

```
<div id="inrlog" style="display:none;">
   <div>name:<input type="text" name="selname[]"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I guess it should be `clone()` out of the `for-loop`

Comment: Avoid use of `global` variables too. `i` looks global here which does not make sense..

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your option tag inside html. Write  instead of only "$v". Then use this code :

```
<select id="sel" class="sel">
    <?php
    $v = 1;
    while ($v <= 10) {
        ?>      
        <option value="<?php echo $v ?>"> <?php echo $v; ?></option>
        <?php
        $v++;
    }
    ?></select>

<button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>

<div id="inrlog">
    <div class="input_name">name:<input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
</div>

//JS
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".add_field_button").click(function () {
                var form_count = $("#sel").val();
                if (form_count) {
                    $(".input_name").not(':first').remove();
                    for (var j = 0; j < form_count; j++) {
                        ele_append = $(".input_name").eq(0).clone();
                        $("#inrlog").append(ele_append);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: thank you for your response, i got the answer from Rayon Dabre. i want that output only. thank u