# Repeat form according to int value selected from select box in laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.3

I'm using [Bootstrap Wizard Form](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/form-wizard-using-tabs). I have setup a select box in step one of the form with numeric values (i.e. 1-5) and I have setup a form in step 2. I want to repeat the form in step 2 according to the value selected in the step 1. I tried [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34764320/how-to-repeat-the-form-data-according-to-integer-value-get-from-the-select-box). It did worked but it messed up my whole wizard. I would be very thankful if anyone could shed some light on this via php or JavaScript.

Comment: I don't the exact use for your forms, but if you can fill in the same form 5 times, it might be easier to just make it a batch upload. Wizard forms guide the user very well, but can become extremely annoying when you have to do repetitive tasks where you just want efficiency. I'd opt for a batch upload where you can edit your uploads in a next screen. Something like the Facebook photo album upload for example.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:
view

```
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">No. of travellers:</label>
    <select onchange='getamount(this.value);' name="pax" id="pax" class="form-control selectpicker pax">
         <option >Select option</option>
          @for ($i = 1; $i <= 8; $i++)
              <option value={{$i}}> {{$i}}</option>
          @endfor
     </select>
</div>

<div id="inrlog"></div>
```

script:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $(".pax").on('change', function() {
 var counter = parseInt(this.value, 10);
 var html = '<form><div class="form-group"><label for="email">Email:</label><input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email"></div><div class="form-group"><label for="pwd">Password:</label><input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password"></div><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label></div><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button></form>';
 var str = "";
 for (var i = 1; i <= counter; i++) {
   str +='<h3 class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">Person '+i+'</h3>'+html+'<br>';
 }
 $("#inrlog").empty().append(str);
   })
});
```